# Confirmations bitcoin

Tags: bittrex

I don't understand why there are no confirmations. It seems that I paid enough fee, but it is still pending.

Address: 1FbQh78uCcqw76jkANnK2AhygWxnAmZ8eM
TxId: e2701d27976656756db913d877cdeced1eb50c7000987a0098e145db86c5f1f2

https://blockchain.info/tx/e2701d27976656756db913d877cdeced1eb50c7000987a0098e145db86c5f1f2

Anyone know what is wrong?

Cheers,
Pieter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You paid around $15 USD for the fees, the current [average transaction fee today](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactionfees.html) is 41 USD. Your transaction will either take quite some time or it will need a higher fee.